# Responsive html div elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have 3 HTML div elements that I'd like to see sit side-by-side on a wide screen but, as the screen width collapses, I'd like to see them become vertical.

For example...

Wide screen:

```
-----------
abc def ghi
-----------
```

Narrow screen:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Currently, having three HTML divs that look as follows (in another div block) only lays them out vertically...

```
<div id="Master_Div">
  <div id="Div_1">
    <p>abc</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Div_2">
    <p>def</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Div_3">
    <p>ghi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe, the answer is tied to media queries and/or responsive design but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Do you have any css for this? If so please add it to the question. This is a really simple thing to do, I am unsure where you are having the issue

Comment: what happens when its big enough to display 2 out of the 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this unless you actually need to apply an ID, classes are easier for multiple divs with one assignment in css, plus they take up less space.

```
html---
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="third">Something here</div>
   <div class="third">Something here</div>
   <div class="third">Something here</div>
</div>

css---
.third {
    width: 33.333333%
    float:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.third {
    width: 100%;
    float:none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) that allow you to control layout for mobile screens, ex:

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

 /* stack vertically */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple media query can do this.

```css
/* Apply inner styles if the viewport's width is at least 500px */
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width:33.3333%;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Master_Div">
  <div class="responsive" id="Div_1">
    <p>abc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive" id="Div_2">
    <p>def</p>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive" id="Div_3">
    <p>ghi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is best resolved by natural design patterns without resorting to media queries. Think about it this way , if you lay out your columns side by side using css `float:left;` and you define some `min-width` value per column. then as soon as the screen width becomes smaller than the width value you defined X 3 , your columns will be laid out vertically